# What was the quote about known things being trivial and unknown things being impossible?

Tags: quote

I am new to this portion of stack exchange and am not sure if this type of question is allowed, but after seeing [this](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/13869/what-was-richard-courants-saying-about-mathematical-research-apart-from-applica), I assume it is.

A while back, I remember reading a quote about math that said something along the lines of “Before you know the answer, it is impossible; once you do, it’s trivial”. I think the quote even used the terms “trivial” and “impossible”, but I can’t find it again.

The closest I’ve found is “In mathematics, there are only two kinds of proofs: Trivial ones, and undiscovered ones”, but that’s not it as the actual quote used “impossible”.

Comment: "*After physicists prove a big result they think it is fantastic but after mathematicians prove a big result they think it is trivial*", [Szpiro](https://mathoverflow.net/a/7342); "*Not only is every mathematical problem solved, but eventually, every mathematical problem is proved trivial*", [Rota, The Pernicious Influence of Mathematics upon Philosophy](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20116936); "*Mathematicians can prove only trivial theorems, because every theorem that's proved is
trivial*", Feynman, Surely You're Joking, Mr. Feynman!

Comment: Feynman's version is [sometimes paraphrased](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trivial.html) as "There are two types of true mathematical propositions: trivial ones, and those which have not yet been proven." I've also heard "Mathematical theorems are either trivial or false", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're referring to this particular quote:

“All of physics is either impossible or trivial. It is impossible until you understand it, and then it becomes trivial.” - Ernest Rutherford

Comment: Do you have a citation for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an official source for the quote.  I've seen it in passing on numerous occasions over the years -- it used to be written on our physics club T-shirts 20 years ago.  It could be apocryphal since a keyword search of the quote brings up countless quotation websites with no citation.  The quote is commonly used, so it's possible OP stumbled across it.